# How do you get the Simplify function to completely simplify an inequality in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify, inequality

I am working on testing whether a function lies in a given range. Somehow, the function Simplify does not provide the correct (obvious) answer. Why is that ?

The main function corresponds to the product of these functions:

```
f1[x_] = a0 + (1 - a0) (1 - Exp[-a1 x]);
f2[x_] = 1 - Exp[-a2  x];
f3[y_] = 1 - Exp[-a3  y];
```

so that

```
f[x_, y_] = f1[x] f2[x] f3[y];
```

The conditions on the parameters are:

```
condParam = 0 < a0 < 1 && a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && a3 > 0;
```

Obviously, using the function Simplify, we get:

```
Simplify[0 < f1[x] < 1, Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]
Simplify[0 < f2[x] < 1, Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]
Simplify[0 < f3[y] < 1, Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]
```

*True*

*True*

*True*

But, somehow, Mathematica does not find that the product of these functions also lies between 0 and 1:

```
Simplify[0 < f[x, y] < 1, Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]
```

*E^(-a1 x - a2 x -
a3 y) (-1 + a0 + E^(a1 x)) (-1 + E^(a2 x)) (-1 + E^(a3 y)) < 1*

Why is that? Although it is not a big deal in this case, this becomes a problem when I try to find the range of more complicated functions.

Using the following command does not solve the issue

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->{"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->100}];
```

Thank you for your help.

T.

Comment: `Simplify[0<f[x,y],Assumptions->condParam&&x>0&&y>0]` returns `True`, It is the `f[x,y]<1` that seems to be causing the problem. Maybe you can use that hint to try to isolate exactly what the problem expression is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I gave a try and there is indeed something weird going on:
`Simplify[E^(a2 x) > 1, Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]`
`Simplify[E^(a3 y) > 1, Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]`
`Simplify[E^(a2 x) + E^(a3 y) > 1,  Assumptions -> condParam && x > 0 && y > 0]`

lead to 

True; 
True; 
E^(a2 x) + E^(a3 y) > 1, respectively; 

I don't understand what is wrong with the summation of exponential functions. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `Simplify[E^(a2 x)+E^(a3 y)>1,E^(a2 x)>1&&E^(a3 y)>1]` Hummm... ;}

Comment: Well that works. :) But is there any way of getting Mathematica to handle this kind of obvious summation of exponential functions?

Comment: What's obvious to one sometimes isn't to another and when one of those is tens of millions of lines of software algorithms inside MMA then who knows. I've been fumbling with all the ideas I've thought of thus far and still can't figure out why the sum<1 won't work. I'm guessing it has to do with the multiple layers of logic needed, but that hasn't helped thus far. I'll keep thinking and trying things. You please do the same. If nothing else works then you might try posting on community.wolfram.com or on mathematica.stackexchange.com and see if either of those finds someone with a working idea.